# Meteor Accounts - user disconnected after a page refresh

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I currently have a problem with the implementation of Accounts Meteor. I've already made several research on the subject, but I find only vague information without get a real answer.

I implemented account-base and account-password and I manage the connection of the user with the method "loginWithPassword" (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithpassword).
No problem with this, the user connects, but when the page is refreshed (either with the browser button or refreshed compiling) the user is disconnected.

Do you know how to fix this or do you have ideas about where I can direct me?

Thanks you in advance for your answer.

Comment: how do you know the user is disconnected ?

Comment: @user5809746 There is no "fix" to this - it's how the login system works. On a refresh, the user will lose her connection to the server so she must go through the authentication process again in order to reconnect. I'd recommend rephrasing the question around an actual implementation problem you are having as the result of the user being temporarily disconnected.

Comment: That's simply not true. When refreshing a Meteor app you stay connected.

Comment: @tarmes I'm not sure how it could stay connected...if the user refreshes the page, the web socket must be re-established, and authentication details will be passed along from the local store rather than a cookie. I'm not sure why user5809746 is not being logged back in automatically, but when a user refreshses the page they are most definitely disconnected and must re-establish their session. If you add a console.log() to Accounts.onLogin(), you will see a log message every time you refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing around with meteor for last few months and not sure 0f what i written below is relevant/appropriate.

Run this from Console after the page refreshes.

Meteor.user()

if you get an object that means you are still logged in. just to be sure you  may explore the user object and look for services>>resume>>logintokens>>0>hashedToken.

if the above step is fine then check the status of ddp by running below

Meteor.status()

if everything is fine in here( i mean if it shows connected) then check for your routes..

Thanks.